# Django CMS, per page CSS Styles

Tags: django-cms

I often use small, page specific CSS files for a page in Typo3 using [css_select](http://typo3.org/extensions/repository/view/css_select). These styles usually apply only to some special element on these pages. Putting these styles in a global file doesn't feel right.

Using css_select I can select a bunch of files that may be included into the page's header, so that it loads it's special styles.

Now I'm looking for a way to do something similar in Django CMS 3. The only built in solution I'd know is to create a new template which seems a bit excessive for a single page where an image needs to be handled a bit differently from all the others, to name just one example.

- Is there a way to do this using nothing but django CMS?
- If not, is there an app that would do that?
- If not, how could an app extend the page admin form in such a way that this function could be added.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could extend the page.

See http://django-cms.readthedocs.org/en/latest/extending_cms/extending_page_title.html

A good example is https://github.com/nephila/djangocms-page-meta

This the above package allows you to add additional meta tags to page header.

Comment: exactly what I was looking for. Thanks and sorry for the delay, got distracted in the meantime.

Comment: Check out sekizai. https://django-sekizai.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ Works perfectly for this.